# Autocomplete decimals in a siunitx table

Tags: tables, siunitx, automation

I'm making a table with numbers with different decimal contents. I'd like to complete automatically with `0` the remaining decimal positions, i.e. in a list of numbers like `1.2`, `2.34` and `3.456` I'd like to print `1.200`, `2.340` and `3.456`. How can I achieve this using siunitx package?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Example Table}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=1.3]}
\midrule
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
\midrule
Parameter 1 & 1\\
Parameter 2 & 1.2\\
Parameter 3 & 2.34\\
Parameter 4 & 4.567\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the manual of `siunitx`, section 5.5 “Post-processing numbers”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Example Table}
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3,round-integer-to-decimal]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
\midrule
Parameter 1 & 1\\
Parameter 2 & 1.2\\
Parameter 3 & 2.34\\
Parameter 4 & 4.567\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The setting can also be enforced with `\sisetup` if it has to hold for the whole `tabular`; if `\sisetup` appears inside `table`, then the setting will be valid only in the environment.

[image]